# Center the terms in an equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I have the following equation:

[image]

Notice how the last two terms are not centered? If I use the code specified below, I would get that effect. Now, what I would like to have is the effect shown in the first term (centered the term "Bias"). You probably also see that since I kind of fail with paint, the first terms are not centered correctly.

Now I was wondering if it is possible to do that in Latex? Notice that it should be centered between the equal sign and the plus sign.

In code form:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Err(x_{0}) &=\left(E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})\right]-f(x_{0})\right)^{2}&+&E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})-E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})\right]\right]^{2}&+&\sigma^{2}_{\epsilon} \\
&=\text{Bias}^{2}&+&\text{Var}(\hat{f}(x_{0})&+&\text{Var}(\epsilon)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Now unfortunately, the terms in the first equation and the second equations are not centered. I was wondering how I can center each term.

Thanks

Comment: `$$...$$` is outdated. Please use `\[...\]` instead. Your first example is also in code form ;-) And provide a MWE, please

Comment: Plus please learn the correct use of the `\text` command, hint: you are not using it right. Define `\Bias`, `\Var` in the preamble using `\DeclareMathOperator\Bias{Bias}`, and `\DeclareMathOperator\Var{Var}`. Var and Bias should be upright in all cases, `\text` is not!

Comment: if you want each line centered separately, use `gathered` instead of `aligned`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\left` and `\right` to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't center the terms, but it's just my opinion.

You can obtain correct spacing around the `=` and `+` symbols with `alignedat` or also with `array` if you prefer centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Err}{Err}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bias}{Bias}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}

\newcolumntype{O}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\Err(x_{0}) &= 
  \bigl(\E[\hat{f}(x_{0})]-f(x_{0})\bigr)^{2} 
  &&+ \E\bigl[\hat{f}(x_{0})-\E[\hat{f}(x_{0})]\bigr]^{2}
  &&+ \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}
 \\
&= \Bias^{2} &&+ \Var(\hat{f}(x_{0})) &&+ \Var(\epsilon)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r O c O c O c O c}
\Err(x_{0}) &=& 
  \bigl(\E[\hat{f}(x_{0})]-f(x_{0})\bigr)^{2} 
  &+& \E\bigl[\hat{f}(x_{0})-\E[\hat{f}(x_{0})]\bigr]^{2}
  &+& \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}
 \\[1ex]
&=& \Bias^{2} &+& \Var(\hat{f}(x_{0})) &+& \Var(\epsilon)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the definitions of the four math operators; the `\newcolumntype` declaration is for the second rendering, it represents the column where the `=` and `+` signs are.

Don't use `\left` and `\right`, that produce awfully oversized fences. Just `\bigl` and `\bigr` are necessary in two places.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In general you should not use `align..` for that kind of construction. If the equations are not numbered a solution is to use `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Bias}{Bias}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
  \begin{array}{rcccccc}
    Err(x_{0}) & = & \left(E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})\right]-f(x_{0})\right)^{2} 
               & + & E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})-E\left[\hat{f}(x_{0})\right]\right]^{2}
               & + & \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}\\
               & = & \Bias^2
               & + & \Var(\hat{f}(x_{0})
               & + & \Var(\epsilon)
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192207/16895) for the rationale for setting the array inter column space to `1.5pt`.